# Ruby on Rails - Bcyrpt update user attributes with password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I want to give the user the opportunity to update some user information. For now only the name and email. The User needs to type the current password to authorize the update. I tried several ways and it comes down to the following problem:

I call a "validate_password" method before updating the user attributes.

users_controller.rb:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])


respond_to do |format|
  if validate_password(params[:password]) && @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Account was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

application_controller.rb:

```
  def validate_password(pswd)
if current_user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pswd, current_user.password_salt)
  true
else
  false
end
```

end

It returns false even with the correct password as "pswd". 
Am I missing something? You can recreate the password hash if you know the correct salt right?

Comment: The 'end' belongs into the code, the format is failing me ;)

Comment: and why are you sure you have this exact hashing when creating user? Also validator can be single line, without if at all, just the condition.

Comment: the "validate" is just my method name. Maybe misleading it's not a validator. More a "check for correct password" method. Creation of the hash: http://pastebin.com/nv09i0ky

Comment: I would also vote for @Jan solution, although things you do work for Ryan. 
Can you try the process from console, just to make sure, that everything works. Since at first look it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `current_user.password_hash` contains a hash created using [`BCrypt::Password#create`](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html), instead of

```
current_user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(...)
```

try

```
BCrypt::Password.new(current_user.password_hash) == passwd
```

Don't do the salting yourself. It's redundant as BCrypt does the salting already.

Another step in a good direction would be to abandon hand-written authentication and use an existing, battle-tested solution, e.g. [Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/devise/info).

Comment: The hash is created like this: http://pastebin.com/nv09i0ky (followed the railscast)

Comment: Can you create it using `BCrypt::Password#create` instead?

Comment: For the login the user authenticates with his email & password. (http://pastebin.com/dvWRXsde).. works without problems. What I'am now trying to achieve is even simpler (no email). My main goals is to understand the basics before using gems, that do all the work for me. (I'm still new to rails). I can't see why it fails now but the email auth in the model is working

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

This way you will avoid password validation when updating.